# URDF to SDF conversion using gzsdf

Tags: urdf, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

As I'm currently trying to tune the dynamic behaviour of my robot modelled in a urdf(.xacro) file, I investigated the various urdf and gazebo tags available in order to see their effect to the simulation respectively.

This thread mainly deals with the conversion from urdf to sdf format using the gzsdf tool. So this thread is probably the first of several threads.

In the following I state my observations and would kindly ask someone to confirm them...or give explanations otherwise ;-)

I use the following setup: Trusty, Indigo, gazebo2_2.2.3-1~trusty_amd64
The robot I'm trying to tune is the Schunk lwa4p_extended. URDFs can be found here [URDFs](https://github.com/ipa-fxm/schunk_modular_robotics/tree/indigo_dev/schunk_description/urdf/lwa4p_extended) and [launch files](https://github.com/ipa-fxm/schunk_robots/tree/indigo_dev/schunk_lwa4p_extended).
Other related links: [gazebo-urdf-tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) and [sdf1.4](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/1.4.html).

I will number the questions so that answers can be referenced accordingly.

---

General questions

1. The SDF version used in my setup (trusty, indigo, gazebo2) is SDF1.4?
2. Where is SDF1.5 used? With gazebo3? Or gazebo4?
3. You can convert a urdf.xacro file to sdf uding the following commands

   rosrun xacro xacro.py robot_lwa4p_extended.urdf.xacro > robot_lwa4p_extended.urdf
   gzsdf print robot_lwa4p_extended.urdf > robot_lwa4p_extended.sdf
4. When spawning a robot in gazebo using `gazebo_ros/spawn_model` the same `gzsdf` is used to convert the parameter `/robot_description` to sdf format which is then used in gazebo?
5. Within a urdf gazebo tag (referencing a link or joint), I can use all tags listed in the [gazebo-urdf-tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf)? I.e.:

   - material, gravity, dampingFactor, maxVel, minDepth, mu1, mu2, fdir1, kp, kd, selfCollide, maxContacts, laserRetro for links
   - kp, kd, stopCfm, stopErp, provideFeedback, cfmDamping, fudgeFactor for joints
6. Within a urdf gazebo tag (referencing a link or joint), I can also use sdf tags from [sdf1.4](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/1.4.html) directly?

---

Tag specific questions

1. `gravity`, `selfCollide` and `self_collide` (gazebo tag for links)
   Adding one of the tags above for a link, an additional tag is added to the resulting sdf file, i.e. there are then **two** `gravity` tags for the same link in the sdf file where the first is always set to true (1) and the second sdf tag holds the value set in the urdf. I assume that when gazebo parses the sdf file, it always finds the first tag using their value, thus always neglecting what has been set in the urdf.
2. `kp`, `kd`, `mu1`, `mu2`, `maxVel`, `minDepth`, `fdir1`, `maxContacts`, `laserRetro`, `dampingFactor` (gazebo tag for links)
   All those tags seem to be converted to sdf correctly.
3. `damping` and `friction` (urdf tag for joints)
   `friction` is currently ignored, i.e. it's value is not even converted into the sdf file?
4. Empty gazebo tag referencing a joint

   ```
   <gazebo reference="${name}_1_joint">
   </gazebo>

   is converted into 

   <physics>
     <ode>
       <limit>
         <cfm>0</cfm>
         <erp>0.2</erp>
       </limit>
     </ode>
   </physics>
   ```
5. `stopCfm`, `stopErp` (gazebo tag for joint)

   ```
   <gazebo reference="${name}_1_joint">
     <stopCfm>0.3</stopCfm>
     <stopErp>0.4</stopErp>
   </gazebo>

   is converted into 

   <physics>
     <ode>
       <limit>
         <cfm>0.3</cfm>
         <erp>0.4</erp>
       </limit>
     </ode>
   </physics>
   ```
6. `cfmDamping`, `implicitSpringDamper`, `cfm_damping`, `implicit_spring_damper` (gazebo tag for joint)
   `cfmDamping` is marked deprecated?
   Both `cfmDamping` and `implicitSpriingDamper``are converted into

   ```
   <physics>
     <ode>
       <implicit_spring_damper>1</implicit_spring_damper>
       <cfm_damping>1</cfm_damping>
       <limit>
         <cfm>0</cfm>
         <erp>0.2</erp>
       </limit>
     </ode>
   </physics>
   ```
7. `kp`, `kd` (gazebo tag for joint)
   Not converted into sdf. Why?
8. `provideFeedback`, `fudgeFactor` (gazebo tag for joint)
   All those tags seem to be converted to sdf correctly.

---

Sorry, if this thread got quite long, but I think it shows some important observations that also could help others.

Confirmation to the observations from the "General questions" section, would help me confirm that I am using the correct tags and that my setup is correct.

The observations from the "Tag specific questions" section, shows some important issues that probably should be documented. Especially the issue anbout `gravity`, `selfCollide` appears to be a bug. Also `kp` and `kd` (for joints) doesn't seem to be correct.

Thank you for reading this to the end ;-)
Any comments or thoughts are highly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7074/urdf-to-sdf-conversion-using-gzsdf/) by [Felix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/350/felix/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kukanani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3181/kukanani/) on 2017-10-12**:
Note that in newer versions of Gazebo, the tool used to convert from URDF to SDF has changed, and it is now `gz sdf -p my_urdf.urdf > my_sdf.sdf`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Great questions. I like the organization. Below are responses.

**General Question Responses**

1. Yes.
2. Gazebo 4.0
3. Yes
4. The sdformat library is used. This library is used in both `gz sdf` and the ros spawn mechanism
5. You should be able to. If you notice a problem, then we have bug. Please let us know if that is the case.
6. Same answer as number 5.

**Tag specific responses**

1. This sounds like a bug. Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/71) to track this problem.
2. Great.
3. Joint friction is under development. See this [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1206). We will add in joint friction support once Gazebo is able to process it.
4. Those are the default values for cfm and erp.
5. Not sure if this is a question.
6. `implicit_sping_damper` replaces `cfm_damping`. Both are set to make sure it's compatible with old and new versions of Gazebo.
7. This is a bug, see this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/71).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/350/felix/) on 2014-09-20**:
Thank you, Nate, for the clarification!

General.6: As to "Using SDF tags in URDF (gazebo extension) directly?" see also this new thread (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7082/using-sdf-tags-in-urdf-gazebo-extension-directly/)

Specific.4: Does it make a difference whether those tags are included in the converted SDF or not? I assume default values are used also if the tags are not set in the SDF file.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-09-22**:
General.6: I'll respond in that question thread.
Specific.4: Default values will be used, even if the values are not present in the SDF file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

i know this feed is a little outdated but i currently have issues when trying to go from xacro->urdf->sdf into gazebo.
I have a fairly complex setup and need to change friction of models in my simulation.

Currently in my xacro i set up a wheel like this:

```
>   <link name="wheel_f_l">
>     <collision name="collision">
>       <geometry>
>         <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}"
>              length="${wheel_length}"/>
>       </geometry>
>     </collision>
>     <visual name="visual">
>       <geometry>
>         <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}"
>           length="${wheel_length}"/>
>       </geometry>
>     </visual>
>     <xacro:solid_cylinder_inertial
>       radius="${wheel_radius}" height="${wheel_length}"
>       mass="${wheel_mass}" gcx="${0}" gcy="${0}" gcz="${0}"/>   
>     </link>
```

I then create a reference like this:

```
<gazebo reference="wheel_r_l">
        <mu1>100</mu1>
        <mu2>100</mu2>
        <maxContacts>1</maxContacts>
    </gazebo>
```

but for some reason my parameters dont survive the conversion to sdf via. gz sdf -p test.urdf > test.sdf.
I use **Gazebo6**.

Help would very much be appreciated!

---

Originally posted by [Franzisdrak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2821/franzisdrak/) with karma: 43 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2